# In rails "get 'vendors/keyword_search', to: 'vendors#keyword_search'" runs "'vendors#show'"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, routes, helper

In a rails app, I am trying to setup a route to a keyword search page. I am trying to pass the following test:

```
scenario 'can perform a keyword search' do
  click_link 'Search'
  click_link 'Keyword search'
  expect(current_path).to eq '/vendors/keyword_search'
  fill_in 'search', with: vendor_one.email
  click_button 'Search suppliers'
  expect(page).to have_content vendor_one.email
  expect(page).not_to have_content vendor_two.email
end
```

So far I have:

in ***/views/vendors/index.html.erb***

```
<div class='col-xs-3'>
  <p><%= link_to 'Keyword search', vendors_keyword_search_path %></p>
</div>
```

in ***/routes.rb***

```
root to: 'homepage#index'

resources :buyers, :vendors

get 'vendors/keyword_search', to: 'vendors#keyword_search'
```

in ***/controllers/vendors_controller.rb***

```
class VendorsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @vendors = Vendor.all
  end

  def show
    @vendor = Vendor.find(params[:id])
  end

  def keyword_search
  end
end
```

I then have a ***/views/vendors/keyword_search.html.erb*** with the following:

```
<div id='main container' class='container-fluid'>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-xs-3'>
    </div>
    <div class='col-xs-6'>
      <h1>suppliers#keyword_search</h1>
    </div>
    <div class='col-xs-3'>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My issue seems to be coming after a click on the 'Keyword search' link. Rather than running `vendors#keyword_search` and loading the '*/views/vendors/keyword_search.html.erb*' template, my path helper `vendors_keyword_search_path` attempts to run `vendors#show` resulting in the following error message (note the first line of stack trace included):

```
1) Buyers searching vendors can perform a keyword search
   Failure/Error: @vendor = Vendor.find(params[:id])

   ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound:
     Couldn't find Vendor with 'id'=keyword_search
   # ./app/controllers/vendors_controller.rb:7:in `show'
```

Help on this would be greatly appreciated, but most of all I really want to understand why it's running `show` and not `keyword_search`.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails processes the routes sequentially. So it matches vendors/keyword_search to vendors#show as that is the first "match" in the routes. It then treats keyword_search as the :id parameter for the show route.

So you should place your route for keyword_search above the resources.

Comment: Thanks, is it best practice to place `resources :resource` at the foot of your roots then? 

I am still a little confused as to why it specifically matched it to show, although I understand that it has run through my routes and come to resources first.

Comment: I'm not sure about best practice, but as it runs through it sequentially if you have more specific requirements they need to be placed above the resources.

Comment: As for matching on show first, have a look at this: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions. The first route rails matched on was equivalent to photos#show. What it did was then treat the text "keyword_search" as the :id parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Try after changing the below line in your route file

```
get 'vendors/keyword_search', to: 'vendors#keyword_search'
```

to

```
match "vendors/keyword_search" => "vendors#keyword_search", :as => :vendors_keyword_search_path
```